# Replace XML bullet points found in feed in classic ASP

Tags: xml, asp-classic

Hey I am currently reading in a XML file which contains bullet list in the following container i.e.

 the average pension contribution rate for executive directors .

I am having a problem with symbol directly before the text of each bullet point I want to remove it i.e Replace(text,"old","new") but i cant seem to find what value that bullet point actually is to replace of that makes sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a hexdump or hex viewer utility, feed the XML file to that, and inspect the character's encoded value directly. From this you can deduce the character code to include in your string using an escape.

Comment: Hey I did not quite understand the above how to remove this from my XML. When Parsed im left with "?" after parsing the XML when i view the original XML this is displayed as an extra space before newline.

Comment: @StevieB Use a unicode aware editor to view the XML, or dump the relevant part as binary. That way you can get the actual character. If you really are getting '?' when parsed, then whatever you're parsing it with is broken - it's more likely whatever you're viewing the parsed result is not understanding that unicode character.